# ST Analog Switch Booster

Tags: stm32

I see the term "analog switch booster" in the ST reference manual for the stm32g071. However, I do not see anything anywhere that explains what it is or does. What exactly is an analog switch booster?

Comment: can you link to that and tell us the page?

Answer (score 2):

[The manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32g071c8.pdf) only says that the booster must be enabled for ADC operation below VDD of 2.4 V, and disabled for VDD above that.

I'd hazard a guess that it's a charge pump used to generate a higher voltage for the analog switches used in the ADC. Generally these switches have a lower on resistance when driven from a higher voltage.

I can imagine the conversation amongst the designers. The entire circuit works over the range 1.7 V to 3.6 V *except* the ADC, which only works above 2.4 V. Do we ditch the ADC, or ditch the lower half of the operating voltage range? Wait, I've got an idea!